# How can work with auto increment process in Neoload?

Tags: java, jquery, neoload

I tested a Education based application, In this application I execute 'Course creation' process. Each course has unique ID.

If I give 50 users, this unique ID not to auto-incremented and the same id apply for all 50 users. But I need to auto increment the courseid to given users. Please give me the solution in Neolaod tool.

Answer (score 1):

Create a counter variable from Variable Manager and set the required initial value, auto-increment value and the maximum value. Once you are done with this, parameterize your Unique ID.

However, this would work only when you know where the unique IDs start and their incremental values. If you are unaware of the pattern in which the unique IDs appear, I would advice you to Handle the Dynamic Value using variable extractors.

Hope that clarifies your doubt.